# Change Docker Root Dir on Red Hat Linux?

Tags: linux, directory, docker

I have a little problem. I have a brand new Red Hat Linux Server and I installed Docker CE for CentOS/Red Hat with the official repositories for Docker CE. Now I see that docker creates the container under `/var/lib/docker`, but my problem is that I use an extra partition for my data under `/data/docker`. How can I change the default root directory for Docker in CentOS/Red Hat?

I tried a few HOWTOs but I get the same problem. I can’t find the configuration. For example, I search for the following files:

- `/etc/default/docker` (I think only for Debian/Ubuntu)
- `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf` (I can't find on my system)
- `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (I can't find on my system)

If I get the docker info I see:

Docker Root Dir: `/var/lib/docker`

Comment: you can create /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf and put something like 'ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --graph /docker  --default-ulimit nofile=1024:4096 -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock' in it in a '[Service]' block. The ExecStart set in /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service is over-ridden. This works Centos 7.3,7.7, Docker version 18.09.6, jan 2020.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stop all running docker containers and then docker daemon. Move "/var/lib/docker" directory to the place where you want to have this data.
For you it would be:

```
mv /var/lib/docker /data/
```

and then create symlink for this docker directory in /var/lib path:

```
ln -s /data/docker /var/lib/docker
```

Start docker daemon and containers.

Comment: You'll also want to run:
    `semanage fcontext -a -e /var/lib/docker /data/docker`

Comment: @jsbillings could you add an explanation why this is useful?

Comment: `semanage fcontext -a -e .... .....` sets up an equivalency class between the original location and the new one, so the files automatically get the right context.

Answer (score 10):

The [Docker documentation on controlling the Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options) suggests that platform independent way to do this is:

edit the /etc/docker/daemon.json file to contain the line

```
{
    "data-root": "/mnt/docker-data",
    (...)
}
```

where `/mnt/docker-data` is the directory where you want the docker images and containers to live.

Then

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

You can check whether it worked by running

```
docker info
```

and look for the contents of the line that start with `Docker Root Dir:`.

Comment: I needed to use "graph" instead of "data-root", but that may be a difference in version.

Comment: This worked for me on Fedora 33. I didn't have the file, created it, works well.

Answer (score 1):

i use fedora 27 
you can look docker deamon help

```
dockerd --help 
--data-root string                        Root directory of persistent Docker state (default "/var/lib/docker")
```

stop docker service

```
systemctl stop docker
```

move docker default folder. i moved to under /data folder.

```
mv /var/lib/docker /data/.
```

open service file

```
vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

change ExecStart variable's parameter.

```
vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

this mine. also i added debug parameter.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -D --data-root /data/docker
```

need deamon reload

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

you can start service

```
systemctl start docker
```

if you can test on command line before service start

```
 dockerd -D --data-root /data/docker
```

it is done.